# trying to await a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get data from database I have an array in which collection of id are present and i try to get data from a database for each id and then send to a client if try something like this:-

```
router.get('/getcart1', async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;`enter code here`
  const data = await cart1.find({ email: email });
  const id = data[0].id;

  let details = await id.map(async (e) => {
    console.log('start');
    console.log(e);
    let data = await books.find({ _id: e });
    console.log('end');
    return data;
  });
  res.json({ data: details });
});
```

the execution is start e start e end end 
ans when we send data details it show empty object i want all details.Inside a loop i have data but outside it show empty object

Comment: what is the value of data[0].id?  You are treating it as an array by doing `id.map` but is it an array?

Comment: async functions return a promise.  you can't use it like that.  you can use `await Promise.all(id.map ... )`

Comment: You cannot `await` an array of promises, you can only await a promise for an array. You're missing a `Promise.all` call.

Comment: actually there's definitely something else wrong with the code.  Always Learning is probably right.  `JSON.stringify(await [Promise,Promise ... ])` should not return an empty object.  Or maybe he meant `[{},{} ...]` as an empty object

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to await an array of `Promises`, that's not going to work, you will need a `Promise.all` around this:

```
let details = await Promise.all(id.map(async (e) => {
  console.log('start');
  console.log(e);
  let data = await books.find({ _id: e });
  console.log('end');
  return data;
}));
```